# Kindle Fire compatibility issue with iScroll

Tags: javascript, android, html, kindle, iscroll

I use iScroll on a website, and everything is fine with all web browser. But when i tried to access it with a Kindle Fire device, i can't scroll on my page.

When i use Android native browser or Firefox/Chrome Mobile, it's working.

I use iScroll the simplest way :

```
var MyScroll = new iScroll('left_wrap');
```

Is there some problems with the Kindle Fire native browser ? (Android 2.3; App Webkit)

Comment: Are you able to share some more code? We have iScroll in use and there hasn't been any problems with Kindle Fire.

And are you using the latest version of iScroll?

Comment: I use iScroll v4.1.9 ; Here a sample of my code : http://jsfiddle.net/ZSPmn/1/

Comment: I can only suspect that this has something to do with position:fixed. Have you tried without that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it using the YUI scrollview, and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because "overflow: auto" touch scrolling is not supported on the Kindle Fire native browser:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna/ref=cm_cd_pg_newest?ie=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1GLDPZMNR1X53&cdPage=1&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx1NHWJIHDRU49Y

Although apparently it is supported on Kindle Fire if you use Mobile FireFox:

http://www.softufacture.com/mobile